# Pagination for ArrayList in JSF2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have one searched arraylist that i am getting from Database for that array list i want to apply paginataion with links First, Prev, Next, Last and Goto page dropdown here i don't want to call database for every request(i.e First,Prev,etc) i want to use arrylist that returned at the time of search.And one more requirement is field level sorting need to do Ascending,descending if user clicks on header field.can any one help me to fix this i want to use only JSF2 no RichFaces,etc

Thank in advance.

Comment: check [using datatables](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html) blog entry from @BalusC

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not want to use rich or prime faces or others? Just use primefaces datatable with paginator="true".

If you don't want it, but want to do it the hard way. I suggest you fetch everything from database. Use a datatable and in the getter of that table, you only give back a portion of your array. (index 10 to 20, or index 20 to 40 or...)
On top or bottom of your datatable you put some outputlinks. These can set the indexes you want to retrieve.

Hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: maybe @user1166528 can't add these kind of libraries into the project he's working at

Comment: could be. Tha's why I explain further another solution. But it is intriguing me why one is unable/not permitted to add these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In case Myfaces Tomahawk is an option for you...

I see it (Myfaces Tomahawk) as a bit different from PrimeFaces/Richfaces cause MyFaces are responsible for the MyFaces JSF Implementation as well (so it could be an excuse for using Myfaces Tomahawk), so you can use the Myfaces JSF implementation + Myfaces Tomahawk

Take a look at the [Myfaces Tomahawk datascroller](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_dataScroller.html)